# Does MS notify when an OS patch is updated?

Tags: patch-management

We know the drill, every Patch Tuesday MS releases a long list of MS13-xx patches. Those typically consist of KB items for individual configurations or servers.

From time to time, though, Microsoft will update old MS13-xx patches with additional or new KB items.

For instance, MS11-025 had a bunch of KBs released on April 12, 2011. KB2455033 is MS11-025: Description of the security update for Visual Studio 2010: April 12, 2011.

Fast forward to June 14, 2011, and Microsoft released more KB items for the *same* MS patch. KB2542054 is MS11-025: Description of te security update for Visual Studio 2010: June 14, 2011.

Now, if an enterprise patch management solution simply looks for the KB items referenced in the actual MS11-025 release, KB254054 will never be applied. Does Microsoft provide updates or at least a courtesy notification that older MS items have been update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... from [the WSUS documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708465%28v=WS.10%29.aspx):

> On the WSUS console, the WSUS update page clearly indicates those updates that have a superseded or superseding relationship with an earlier version. The Details tab also includes "Superseded by" and "Supersedes" status information for updates, in addition to KB links containing more information about each update.